# error: request for member which is of non-class type

Tags: c++, qt

ЗдравствуйтеОлл!
Помогите понять - то ли лыжи не едут, то ли я... Вот только где, в чем...?

Переписываю пример из книжки - "Qt 5.3, Профессиональное программирование на C++", Макс Шлее, БХВ-Петербург, 2015
со страниц 417 и далее ("Листинг 28.9 Пример для централизованного использования объекта настроек")
Компилятор обзывается так:

```
error: request for member 'settings' in 'App::theApp', which is of non-class type 'App*()'
```

А код такой:

```
class myApp : public QApplication {

private:
    QSettings*  m_pSettings;

public:
    myApp(int argc, char** argv, const QString& sOrgName, const QString& sAppName):QApplication(argc,argv)
    {
        m_pSettings = 0;

        QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName(sOrgName);
        QCoreApplication::setApplicationName(sAppName);

        m_pSettings = new QSettings(sOrgName,sAppName,this);
    }
public:
    static myApp* theApp(){ return (myApp*) qApp; }
    QSettings* settings(){ return m_pSettings; }
};

TMyControl::TMyControl(int iCtrlNum){
QSettings *pGearStngs = myApp::theApp->settings();

    ...
```

---

> Qt Creator 3.5.1 based on Qt 5.5.1 / Ubunt'а 16.04

Comment: `myApp::theApp()->...` круглые скобочки

Comment: Ну и слепая же я тетеря! :о) Это ж надо было _функцию без скобок вызывать_! :lol:
@Alexander Chernin : Спасибо!

Comment: Ночью часа три на это убил. Сначала думал, что не все инклуды сделал, а потом где-то на форумах нашел аналогичную жалобу, так там ответ был - "_либо у вас компилятор старый, либо в опциях ком.строки задан рестрикт на C98_", вот я в эту сторону и начал рыть. Ну и зарылся до полного "восторга". Не знаю пока как тут "спасибо" оставить, узнаю - вернусь! :о)